# Line bundle on product scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Let $k$ be a field, $X$ be a complete variety over $k$, $V$ be an open subvariety of $X$, $Y$ be a scheme over $k$. Suppose $L$ is a line bundle on $V\times Y$. If $L|_{V\times\lbrace y\rbrace}$ extends to a line bundle on $X\times\lbrace y\rbrace$ for every closed point $y$ of $Y$, does the line bundle $L$ extend to $X\times Y$?

What if a stronger condition is assumed ,namely for any functor $\phi\colon\operatorname{Pic}(V\times Y) \to \operatorname{Pic}(V)$ (here $\operatorname{Pic}$ denotes the Picard functors), the line bundle $\phi(L)$ on $V$ extends to $X$. Does $L$ extends to $X\times Y$?

Edit: $X$ is assumed to be smooth i.e. a smooth complete variety.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  That is not true.  Let $X$ be a nodal plane quartic curve, let $Y$ be the normalization of $X$, let $V$ be the open complement of the node, i.e., the maximal open subscheme over which $Y\to X$ is an isomorphism, and let $L$ be the invertible sheaf of the effective Cartier divisor in $V\times Y$ that is the image of the graph of the open inclusion of $V$ in $Y$.

Comment: Hi @JasonStarr , thank you for your answer. I should've said $X$ is smooth. Would my statements be true?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome new contributor.  This is not true, even if $X$ is smooth.  One example permutes the role of $X$ and $Y$ in my previous example.

Let $X$ be a smooth, geometrically connected, projective curve of genus $g>0$.  Let $f:X\to Y$ be the normalization of a nodal curve with a single node $p$ that is a $k$-rational point.  For instance, $Y$ could be a nodal plane quartic, and $X$ could be the normalization (a genus $3$ curve).  Assume that the preimage of $\{p\}$ in $X$ is split, i.e., $\{r',r''\}$ for $k$-rational points $r',r''$ of $X$.

Let $V$ be the open complement of $\{r',r''\}$ in $X$.  Denote the graph morphism of the restriction of $f$ to $V$ as follows, $$\Gamma:V\to V\times Y.$$  The image of this graph morphism is a prime Cartier divisor in $V\times Y$.  Denote by $L$ the invertible sheaf on $V\times Y$ associated to this Cartier divisor.

The pullback of this Cartier divisor to $V\times X$ does extend to a Cartier divisor on $X\times X$.  Every such extension is of the form $$D_{c',c''} = \underline{\Delta} + \text{pr}_1^*\left(c' \underline{r'} + c''\underline{r''}\right).$$

For each of these extended Cartier divisors, the restrictions over $X\times \{r'\}$ and over $X\times \{r''\}$ are not rationally equivalent.  Indeed, if they were, then $\underline{r'}$ and $\underline{r''}$ would be rationally equivalent, so that the genus $g$ equals $0$.  (This was my reason for working with smooth curves of positive genus.)  Since $X\times X$ is smooth, the homomorphism from the group of rational equivalence classes of Cartier divisors to the Picard group is an isomorphism.  Thus, every invertible sheaf on $X\times X$ that extends the pullback of $L$ has non-isomorphic restrictions over $X\times\{r'\}$ and over $X\times\{r''\}$.  Therefore each extended invertible sheaf on $X\times X$ is **not** isomorphic to the pullback of an invertible sheaf on $X\times Y$.

**Edit**.  In the example above, for every Zariski cover $Y'\to Y$, the same result holds.  However, there is an étale cover $Y'\to Y$ such that the invertible sheaf extends to $X\times Y'$.  For an example where there is no such extension even after an étale cover, instead of letting $X\to Y$ be the normalization of a nodal curve, let is be the normalization of a cuspidal curve.  Then the same construction gives an invertible sheaf $L$ on $V\times Y$ such that for every étale cover $Y'\to Y$, there is no extension of the invertible sheaf to $X\times Y'$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example and detailed elaboration! I realize I only want to consider the extension result locally on $Y$. So I have a further question:  Can the line bundle $L$ (in your example and in general) extends at least locally on $Y$ i.e. there exists a (Zarisiki, etale or fppf) cover $\lbrace Y_i \to Y \rbrace$ such that $L|_{V \times Y_i}$ extends to $L|_{X \times Y_i}$ for each $i$ ?

Comment: That still does not work.  Let me modify the example above to explain this.

Comment: Thx @JasonStarr. I don't see your modification. But I guess you were trying to say that there is no neighborhood $U_p$ around $p$ such that $L|_{V \times U_p} $extends to $L|_{X \times U_p}$ for similar reason? I'm not entirely sure though...

Comment: Sorry about that; yesterday was hectic.  I just added the modification now.

Comment: Thx for patiently answering my questions! I need to think about how the argument in the etale situation works.. Anyway does it also imply there is no extension after an fppf cover?

Comment: I believe that there is an extension after an fppf cover . . .

Comment: Uhhh.. Why? Do you mean in general the line bundle extends fppf locally on Y? Do you have a proof for that?

Comment: Yes, I believe that there is an fppf cover of $Y$ such that the pullback invertible sheaf extends.  Essentially, I believe the two issues identified in my answer are the only obstructions to extension.  These obstructions are eliminated by etale covers and ramified fppf covers.

Comment: So are you expecting that if $X$ is any smooth complete curve ( i.e. 1-dimensional case)  then any line bundle $L$ on $V \times Y$ does extend to $X \times Y$ fppf locally on $Y$? I've got no clue how to prove this though..

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I expect.  I will try to write a proof soon.

Comment: That'll be great. Thx a lot!

Comment: I am probably not going to have time to write a proof soon.  There are three key steps.  First, by Zariski's Main Theorem, for the normalization $\widetilde{Y}$ of $Y$, every extension of the Cartier divisor on $X\times \text{Spec}\ k(Y)$ extends uniquely to $X\times \widetilde{Y}$.  Next, by Artin approximation (or something simpler), after base change by an etale extension, the irreducible containing a specified closed point of $Y$ are geometrically irreducible.  Finally, a sufficiently ramified fppf cover factors through the normalization.

Comment: "geometrically irreducible" --> "unibranch"

Comment: I haven't really figured out your sketched proof tbh.. But are you putting any assumption on $Y$?

Comment: So this is what I understand so far (only the outline) : given a line bundle $L$ on $V \times Y$, by step 1, the pullback $\tilde{L}$ of $L$ to $V \times \tilde{Y}$ extends to  $X \times \tilde{Y}$. By step 3, there exists an fppf cover $Y' \to Y$ s.t. it factors through $\tilde{Y} \to Y$, so the pullback $L'$ of $L$ to $V \times Y'$ extends. But what's the significance of Step 2? Also which version of Zariski' main theorem are you referring to and is $Y$ arbitrary scheme (i.e. without further assumption) ? Excuse my ignorance. Anyway,  thx again for your continuous answers.